# Keras giving unexpected output for simple binary classification

Tags: neural-network, keras

Here is a simple keras neural network that attempts to map 1->1 and 2->0 (binary classification)

```
X = [[1] , [2]]
Y = [[1] , [0]]

from keras.callbacks import History 
history = History()

from keras import optimizers

inputDim = len(X[0])
print('input dim' , inputDim)
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', input_dim=inputDim))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.009, decay=1e-10, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd , metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X,Y , validation_split=0.1 , verbose=2 , callbacks=[history] , epochs=20,batch_size=32)
```

Using SGD optimizer :

optimizers.SGD(lr=0.009, decay=1e-10, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

Output for epoch 20 :

```
Epoch 20/20
0s - loss: 0.5973 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.4559 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
```

If I use the adam optomizer :

```
sgd = optimizers.adam(lr=0.009, decay=1e-10)
```

Output for epoch 20 :

```
Epoch 20/20
0s - loss: 1.2140 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.2930 - val_acc: 1.0000
```

Switching between adam and sgd optimizers appears to reverse values for acc and val_acc . val_acc = 1 using adam but as acc is 0 , how can validation accuracy be at maximum and training accuracy be at minimum ?

Comment: Is `X` and `Y` those shown at the top of your code?? It's absolutely impossible to learn from 1 sample and get a good validation at another sample. If this is the case, you need data! Also, using a `Dense(1)` after a `Dense(1)` is not very effective.

Comment: Yes. This is a point also. Your dataset is to small for validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sigmoid` after `sigmoid` is a really bad idea. E.g. in this [paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a.html) it's written why `sigmoid` suffers from a *so-called* saturation problem. Moreover - when you use `sigmoid` after `sigmoid` you push the overall saturation of your network to by sky-rocketing in fact. To understand why - notice that the output from a first layer is always from an interval `(0, 1)`. As `binary_crossentropy` tries to make this output (transformed as linear transformation) as close to `+/- inf` as possible this makes your network to have extremely high weights. This is probably causing your total instability.

In order to solve your problem, I would simply leave only one layer with `sigmoid` as your problem has a linear separation property.

**UPDATE:**
As @Daniel mentioned - when you split your dataset containing two examples you end-up having one example in a dataset and other in a validation set. This is causing this weird behavior.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a problem in such small models.

Comment: Actually it is. The weights of a second layer needs to grow a lot in order to solve this task.

Comment: I've trained a lot of models like that. Including a U-net using 'tanh' instead of 'relu' in all the 19 convolutional layers. (For this matter, 'tanh' is pretty much the same as 'sigmoid').

Comment: Actually these are totally different activations. `Tanh` is 0-centered. This is really important when you want to turn off an unit. Moreover you need to compute exp function